# Promoting on Bible commentary sites

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

A while back, Ami wrote on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2592687#2592687):

> [Wouldn't] it be cool for hermeneutics.SE to have a sister site housing a commentary on the Bible being collaboratively edited by members of this site[?]

And I think that would be awesome.  But it seems unlikely any of us will build such a site anytime soon.  (Please, prove me wrong!)

So instead, I've been looking around for sites that we could post links to our questions on particular verses as a form of site promotion and to organize our content by verse in the Bible.  Understandably, many of the major Bible-hosting sites don't allow random folks to post content or links.  So there are a limited number of options out there:

- [YouVersion](http://www.youversion.com)

  I've written two public notes over there and only [one](http://www.youversion.com/notes/3942059) now remains.  When I go to the verse I wrote about, I can't find my note in the flood of other people's content (which is a very mixed bag).
- [Tagged Tanakh](http://www.taggedtanakh.org/)

  It doesn't include the Christian Scriptures and it appears to be little used.  But I was able to post a comment on [Genesis 6:14](http://www.taggedtanakh.org/Remark/Thread/44897200-2224-458d-9344-ffa7a2d7892f) with a link back to our site.  The interface takes some getting used to, however.  (Also, I sometimes have a timeout when I try to load pages on the site.  I don't know if the site is often down or if I'm just unlucky.)
- [Verse By Verse Bible Commentary](http://VBVBC.org)

  I just discovered this because of [a link back](http://www.vbvbc.org/bible-verse/matthew25-1) to one of Richard's answers.  It's a dead simple site and its users already seem open to linking to our content.  (Actually, someone [scraped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) the entire post, including the vestigial "linkimprove this answer", and pasted it there.  Fortunately, they *did* link to the answer.)  Judging from that one page, I'm not sure the tone of that site fits with ours, however.

All three of these could be sources for finding passages that people have unresolved questions about.

Have you discovered any other sites where we can promote ourselves?  Do you see any pitfalls with posting links to our content from these sites?